# iOS GoogleSignIn: Hide sign in confirmation message box

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-signin

I am trying to use GoogleSignIn for my current app. The sign in works, however I keep getting the confirmation message box everytime I trigger the sign in process:

[image: Description]

I have seen Apps where this message box does not appear when users sign in, so am I doing something wrong here?

I followed this tutorial here to implement the sign in: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/google-signin

Another strange thing is that the application open url function never gets called in my project(SDK 11.4 with deploy target 11.0):

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any])
  -> Bool {
    return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url,
                            sourceApplication:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String,
                            annotation: [:])
}
```

I made breakpoints, uninstalled and installed the app again, but it never got called :-/

Any help is appreciated :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its the default behaviour, if user not signed in its request the permission for initially, so add this in your code  as like

```
 if GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().hasAuthInKeychain() == true {
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signInSilently()
    } else {
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()
    }
```